# Better Domain model for creating API

Tags: java, api, domain-driven-design

I want to create an Core API for my application which takes care of talking to database for obtaining/persisting entity objects to/from DB. Then this Core API can be used by Web app or create a REST layer on top of it.

I am building a Forum application and I am creating domain entities like:

```
class User
{
    int id;
    String username;
    ...
    List<Post> posts;

}

class Post
{
    int id;
    String title;
    ...
    User postedBy;
}
```

I am thinking of whether Post class should contain **User** object referring to the user who posted it or just hold **user_id** (integer) only.

Following are scenarios which says both are valid options.

If we want to display a **Post** along with name/email of the user who posted it then we should have User object. On the other hand, API consumers might try to navigate through Object graph which is not fully loaded.

i.e, Client can try to navigate **post.getPostedBy().getPosts()** which returns null or empty list/set and may conclude this user doesn't post anything yet.

If it is integer user_id property client will call another method to get list of posts by the user_id.

So which option is better to hold a reference to parent relationship?

Comment: I would change `post.getPostedBy().getPosts()` to `post.getPosts(User)` per [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: I mentioned post.getPostedBy().getPosts() just as an example. Anyway post has getPostedBy() method which returns a User instance and client can invoke getPosts() on that user instance. If client has User instance he might call user.getPosts() instead of post.getPosts(user) right. Am I missing something?

Comment: kind of Lazily load the getPosts() as and when it is called from the Post object. Will it help ?

Comment: It would be a Core API which serves completely detached objects to (web/rest) clients. No Hibernate/JPA lazy loading works for me :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that Post should hold just a user_id because storing of Post does not need to store User - it is not one Aggregate Root.

But speaking of local and remote API, sending messages between objects depends also on the latency. If the latency is greater than a local call - let's say thru a REST API, you want to send as much information as possible in one call to avoid multiple calls. However that would make you Domain Model ugly for only local calls (within one application - one machine etc).

In other words REST API would send DTO with more information (eg. Post Data together with User Data) using some Remote Facade objects - see "Remote Facade" in PoEAA. But the Domain Model would be modelled for the best structure as User and Post class and fetched by Repositories - PostRepository.getPostsByUser() or similar.

Answer (score 0):

These two classes works as a POJO or data objects right?
If it is like that means you have one User table and one Posts table then i think you should have one more third one which only have the Id's of these two.
Using that you can easily locate which user has posted which post or which post is posted by which user.

For e.g.
public class UserPosts {

```
private User user;
private Post post;


public UserPosts() {
}
```